# Double Summation Over a constant

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Can someone please help me explain this double summation? I can't see why its n-k+1?
$$
d(I) = \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^k l_{i_j} = \sum_{k=1}^n \left( n-k+1 \right) l_{i_k}
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\begin{array}{cccccccc}
\ell_{i_1}\\
\ell_{i_1}&\ell_{i_2}\\
\ell_{i_1}&\ell_{i_2}&\ell_{i_3}\\
\ell_{i_1}&\ell_{i_2}&\ell_{i_3}&\ell_{i_4}\\
\vdots &\vdots&&&\ddots\\
\ell_{i_1}&\ell_{i_2}&\ell_{i_3}&\ell_{i_4}&\cdots&\ell_{i_n}
\end{array}$

The way the summation is originally written you read it from left to right and then from top to down.

Try reading it instead from top to down followed by from left to right.

Comment: Thanks I can see this series clearly from  what you have but does it mean i should see it from bottom to top  "n-k+1" as n > k at every point so the value is decreasing

Comment: @kusiroll if it helps you to see it better, note that the height of the triangle I drew is $n$.  Letting $k$ denote which column we are referring to and letting $k$ start from $1$, we have the number of empty spaces in the column is going to be $k-1$, so the number of nonempty entries in the column will be $n-(k-1)=n-k+1$.

Comment: this really helped!

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to see why this is true if, in the final expression, you relabel the dummy variable $k$ as $m$. The term $l_{i_m}$ is included in the left-hand sum once for each value of $k$ from $1$ to $n$ inclusive satisfying $k\ge m$. There are $n-m+1$ such values, as in the final expression.

Comment: thanks  i was just focused on how the second summation really translates to n-k+1